# If $x^2+y^2-xy-x-y+1=0$ ($x,y$ real) then calculate $x+y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^2+y^2-xy-x-y+1=0$ ($x,y$ real) then calculate $x+y$

Ideas for solution include factorizing the expression into a multiple of $x+y$ and expressing the left hand side as a sum of some perfect square expressions.

Comment: If it is required that $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then you should add this requirement to your post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $s=x+y$ and $d=x-y$. Then $x=(s+d)/2$ and $y=(s-d)/2$. Making this substitution, we find that
$$
x^2+y^2-xy-x-y+1=\frac{3d^2}{4}+\frac{(s-2)^2}{4}.
$$

Hence, being a sum of squares, if the original expression is zero, $d=0$ and $s-2=0$. This means that $s=x+y=2$, with $x=y$.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$2(x^2+y^2-xy-x-y+1)=(x-y)^2+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2.$$ The right-hand side (for real $x$ and $y$) is equal to $0$ if and only if $x=y=1$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be real.

Let $s=x+y$ and $p=xy$; then your equation becomes
$$
s^2-2p-p-s+1=0
$$
or
$$
p=\frac{s^2-s+1}{3}
$$
The equation
$$
z^2-sz+p=0
$$
must have real roots; its discriminant is
$$
s^2-4p=-\frac{(s-2)^2}{3}\le0
$$
so we have $s=2$ (and $p=1$).

Comment: What does  z  stand for?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Any variable; the roots of the equation are precisely two numbers whose sum is $s$ and product is $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $x+y$ is not determined by the first equation. For $x=0$ we obtain $y^2-y+1=0$, so that $x+y=\frac{\pm \sqrt{-3}+1}{2}$. This is certainly not equal to $2$.

Comment: For $x=0 $ there's no real value for $y$

Comment: Doe it say somewhere that $y$ need to be real ?

Comment: In your opinion,what's wrong with the above two Correct answers?

Comment: They only hold for real numbers. But Andre is saying this explicitly, so the answers are not wrong. You could just add "for real $x,y$".